# Vim */dyn support

Tags: vim, python, ruby

What does mean the plus sign before `*/dyn` in the `:version` command's output, e.g.:

```
+python/dyn +python3/dyn +ruby/dyn +tcl/dyn
```

I didn't find any useful documentation on it. When I run `:echo has('python3')` Vim returns 0. When I run `:python3 print('hi')` it says `E370: Could not load library python31.dll` meaning I should install python (as I understand).

So I just *can't see the difference* between `-*/dyn` and `+*/dyn`. What does plus sign give to us? Also what's the difference from `dyn`-less feature, e.g. `+python`?

Answer (score 8):

The `+` means that vim binary has that feature. The /dyn means it is dynamically loaded and may or may not have the feature depending on whether or not it can find the dll.

see `:help python-dynamic`.

Comment: And what is the difference between dyn and not-dyn ?

Comment: dyn means that it only looks for the library if you try to use those features (that's why you only see an error when you try to use python features). notdyn means it always loads the library.

Comment: Also note that in my case vim python/dyn is not working on Ubuntu 16.10 :( 
Still trying to figure out how to make that work.. Because it compiles fine and I enabled --enable-pythoninterp=yes so no idea why it goes ahead with dyn support